# Is using a register chain feeding into a LFSR sufficient to generate "true random numbers" inside an FPGA?

Tags: fpga, random-number

One way to generate random numbers is to pseudo-random numbers. Otherwise, one would need a special mechanism to generate them using dedicated hardware. However, (For FPGAs specifically) why not just rely on delay chains and register their output while perhaps feed it into an LFSR to generate true random numbers?

EDIT:
The delay between a delay chain made up of logic gates depends on temperature and some other factors. Why not use this to create true random numbers? The randomness shall rely on temperature to an extent.

Comment: You need some external input for a true random number generator. If you can predict the future state from the current state, then it is not random. The question is where do you get the data for your registers? I think you need to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: One trick on an FPGA is to use a free-running clock of unpredictable frequency (will depend on external conditions) like a ring oscillator or simple internal oscillator to clock the LFSR. This makes it much harder to predict values read from the system/CPU domain - but be careful of clock domain crossing!

Comment: You'll have hard time synthesizing an "undeterministic enough" delay chain in regular FPGA logic. First, the typical synthesis tools will optimize your whole design out, or barf huge synthesis errors. You can probably get around that with a few tricks, but I'm not sure the results will be a true random number.

Comment: Generating true random numbers is *hard*.  Have you done web searches on the term?  Any easy technique has been thought of, and flaws have been pointed out.  There are various hard techniques currently in use commercially (I like the wall of lava lamps, myself), but even those have at least theoretical flaws.

Comment: *"The randomness shall rely on temperature to an extent."* It depends more on voltage variations which again are greatly influence by power supply noise which depends on what is switching: thus the previous random number generated.

Comment: What do you need your random numbers for?  If the answer is something cryptographic, there are standards for how to assess the quality of the RNG design. It's a non-trivial problem, as others have mentioned.

Comment: Since random numbers need a seed and to get truly random numbers we might use the white noise or some other random property in an electronic circuit, I thought that using a register chain that shall have varying delays depending on temperature is a good candidate to generate the seed. This is a general knowledge question and not application specific.

Comment: Or just measure the internal temperature of your chip using on-chip ADC, and keep XORing it with your pseudo-random numbers :)